# Multiline comments in Dockerfiles

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is there a fast way to comment out multiple lines in a Dockerfile?

I know that I can add `#` at the beginning of each line. But if there are many lines this is too much work. In some languages there are multiline comments such as `/* ... */`, which makes commenting out large parts of a file very fast.

Comment: `M-x comment-region` will work in Emacs; `.,.+4s/^/# /` will comment out the next five lines in vi.

Comment: Any modern IDE will allow you to select lines with mouse and do a simple control + / to comment all of them

Comment: Some community editions of JetBrains' IDE do not recognize Dockerfiles. To still be able to use the control + / shortcut, create a new file type, set "Line comment" to "#" and associate your Dockerfile with the newly created file type.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As of today, no.

According to [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#format) documentation:

> **Docker treats lines that begin with # as a comment**, unless the line is
>   a valid parser directive. A # marker anywhere else in a line is
>   treated as an argument.:

There is no further details on how to comment lines.

As said by some comments already, most IDE will allow you to perform multiline comments easily (such as `CTRL + /` on IntelliJ)

Comment: `CTRL + / ` works well in with VScode single or multi.

Comment: `Cmnd + /` for Vscode running on Mac.

Answer (score 20):

There is no mentioning of multiline comments in [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#format)

I also paste here the relevant part for simplicity:

> Docker treats lines that begin with # as a comment, unless the line is
>   a valid parser directive.
>   A # marker anywhere else in a line is treated as an argument.
>   This allows statements like:

```
# Comment  
RUN echo 'we are running some # of cool things'
```

> **Line continuation characters are not supported in comments.**

On the other hand you can achieve the requested result easily with any modern IDE / Text Editor.

This is an example using [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) (Select text and then control + /).

You can achieve the same result with [VsCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/), [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), [JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/) products (IntelliJ, PyCharm, PHPStorm etc.) and almost 100% of the IDEs / Text Editors I know and use.

[image]

Comment: A+ for the visuals

Answer (score -1):

good solution in VSCode (and many other IDEs) would be:
select all lines that you want to comment out. Hit TAB three times. Now press CTRL+F and search for three TAB spaces ('            ') and then replace all with '# '. All lines that had three TAB spaces in front of it now have a '# ' in front of it.

Comment: It could work, but you risk changing places you didn't intend to. VSCode has better solutions for this case, like choosing a specific file or just selecting the whole block you want to comment and `ctrl/cmd + /` (check @pitto's answer)